# zend framework partial not render echo on ajax request

Tags: zend-framework, jquery, echo, partial, renderpartial

I'd like to render a partial as a response to an ajax request in my controller action.
My goal is to echo a [Twitter Bootstrap Alert](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#alerts) when ajax request is successful.

Here is my action (`redigeraLottningAction`):

```
if($this->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest()){
    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender();
    $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
    echo $this->view->partial('partial/alert-ajax.phtml', array('type' => 'success', 'msg' => 'Lyckat! Lottningen är nu sparad.'));
}
```

And my partial (`alert-ajax.phtml`):

```
<div id="alert-msg" class="alert alert-<?= $this->type?> fade in">
    <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert" href="#">×</a>
    <p><?= $this->msg?></p>
</div>
```

**The problem is that the php scripts in the partial is outputed as text. This is what it looks like in the browser with variables not rendered:**

```
<div id="alert-msg" class="alert alert-<?= $this->type?> fade in">
    <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert" href="#">×</a>
    <p><?= $this->msg?></p>
</div>
```

And the jquery part:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#lottning-spara').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/turnering/redigera-lottning',
            cache: false,
            data: {id: getParam("turnering"), klass_id: getParam("klass"), type: "spara", lottning: $('#lottning_str').val()},
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function(msg){
                $('#alert-div').html(msg);
            },
            error: function(){
                $('#alert-div').html('Error!');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Any ideas why the php in partial is not rendered??

**Edits are bold.**

**Problem Solved.
The alert-ajax.phtml file was a different charset type.**

Comment: are you sure it goes to partial/alert-ajax.phtml page?

Comment: @Zuber Surya Yes it's definitely that page.

Comment: you should try @Ronn0 code and try giving extra comments to check

Comment: Done that. The problem is that the php scripts in the partial is outputed as text.

Comment: try commenting out `$this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender();` and see what happens, this maybe part of the issue.

Comment: I thought the same thing but thats just gives me the view rendered again + this code from the partial:


<�div id="alert-msg" class="alert alert-<�?php echo $this->type; ?> fade in">
<�a class="close" data-dismiss="alert" href="#">�<�/a>
<�p><�?php echo $this->msg; ?><�/p>
<�/div>

Comment: There's a part of the problem i guess, there seems to be something wrong with your charset.

Try paste it in notepad and copy+paste it again. It sounds strange, but maybe that'll solve te problem.

Comment: I installed a new editor and noticed that the charset was on auto. Changed charset and created a new file and now it working lika a charm.

I'm new here so should I do anything whit this question now when the problem is solved?

Comment: @adamnyberg you should write an answer with what the issue was, then mark resolved with your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved. The `alert-ajax.phtml` file was a different charset type.

Answer (score 1):

What if you try this:

```
<div id="alert-msg" class="alert alert-<?php echo $this->type; ?> fade in">
<a class="close" data-dismiss="alert" href="#">×</a>
<p><?php echo $this->msg; ?></p>
</div>

if($this->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest()){
    $this->view->assign(array('type' => 'success', 'msg' => 'Lyckat! Lottningen är nu sparad.'));
    echo $this->view->render('partial/alert-ajax.phtml');
    exit;
}
```

Comment: What about this:

Assign all vars and do this:

    echo $this->view->render('partial/alert-ajax.phtml');

Comment: Delete:
    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender();
    $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();

And exit; after the ->render();

Comment: I highly appreciate the time your time but the same thing happens.